# Given a word, find other words in an array with same length and same characters

Tags: java

I tried solving the problem in the following manner; I am just a beginner and wanted to know my mistakes and a more efficient way with better time complexity (if any).

```
    public class d3 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    String Search="loop";
    String[] letters = Search.split("") ;
    int counter;

    String[] words={"pole","pool","lopo","book","kobo"};

    for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
    {
        counter=0;
        String ssplit[] = words[i].split("");
        for(int j=0;j<words[i].length();j++)
        {

            if(letters.length==ssplit.length)
            {
            for(int k=0;k<letters.length;k++)
            {
                    if(letters[j].equals(ssplit[k]))
                        {counter++;
                        ssplit[k]="*";
                break;


                        }



            }
            if (counter == 4)
            {
                System.out.println(words[i]);

            }

        }
            }


    }

}
}
```

Comment: Hi Aditya. Do you have to use arrays for the words and characters or can you use another structure ?

Comment: @gervais.b I'm currently not too familiar with other data structures. But I'm open to suggestions. Is there a better option than using arrays?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thank you for pointing out the bug. I'll try to fix it and update the question as soon as possible.

Comment: Just for inspiration, here's something to consider, without going into the depth of a full answer. If I understand correctly, your goal is to return all the words from your dictionary that contain the same length and character set as your input word. One approach might be to take your dictionary and for every word sort the characters in alphabetical order. Then generate a one-to-many map of the sorted versions of the words to all the words they can make up. Then, once you possess such a map, perform the same operation on the input word, and you're returning a simple key/value lookup; O(1).

Comment: The advantage to such an approach would be that it can process your dictionary offline, offloading the work of testing for your condition and effectively creating a hash index for your search criteria. While generating such a map might take a while, it would only need to be done when the dictionary is modified, while making your performance of searching for these words extremely good, since you can instantly skip to your answer without ever processing any irrelevant words. This approach would make sense if you have a dictionary that stays the same for many inputs.

Comment: @NateGardner you should have made an answer from your good suggestion ;-)

Comment: @NateGardner Can you please explain what you mean by "one-to-many map of the sorted versions of the words". Why do I need to do that? Once I arrange the characters of all the words in the dictionary alphabetically, I could do the same with the input word and then simply compare it with the entries in the dictionary one by one without getting into comparing each character individually.

Comment: @Aditya, an example of an entry in the one-to-many map would look like this: `"elop": ["lope", "pole"]`. Thus every word in your dictionary would enter this map. let's say the user enters the word "pole." I understand the goal of your program is to return a list of words from your dictionary of the same length that use exactly the same letters, but in any order. Thus all you need to do in order to complete this operation, after having created a one-to-many map, is to sort the letters in the word "pole" to "elop", then access the `elop` key in your map, and return the associated values.

Comment: There are essentially two operations your code must complete:

1. Reduce the dictionary set to words of the same length.
2. Further reduce the dictionary set to words that have the same character frequency.

Because maps directly access the information you want if you know its associated key, both of these steps can be reduced to O(1), leaving the only complex work sorting the input string's characters to its equivalent key, which is O(n) where n is the length of the input string. For input strings with fewer characters than your dictionary has words, this is the most efficient solution.

Comment: @NateGardner I'll definitely look into and try the alternative solution you provided. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitespace is very important for readability. For posting to Stack Exchange sites I recommend replacing tabs with spaces, because otherwise the site does that for you and the tabstops might not match. Here, though, the whitespace is so crazy that I think you need to look at configuring your IDE to pretty-print the code. Reformatting so that I can understand the structure:

> ```
> public class d3 {
>     public static void main(String[] args){
>         String Search="loop";
>         String[] letters = Search.split("") ;
>         int counter;
>
>         String[] words={"pole","pool","lopo","book","kobo"};
>
>         for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
>         {
>             counter=0;
>             String ssplit[] = words[i].split("");
>             for(int j=0;j<words[i].length();j++)
>             {
>                 if(letters.length==ssplit.length)
>                 {
>                     for(int k=0;k<letters.length;k++)
>                     {
>                         if(letters[j].equals(ssplit[k]))
>                         {
>                             counter++;
>                             ssplit[k]="*";
>                             break;
>                         }
>                     }
>                     if (counter == 4)
>                     {
>                         System.out.println(words[i]);
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

---

#### Names

Java convention is that camel-case names which start with a capital letter are types (classes, interfaces, etc), so `Search` as the name of a variable is unexpected.

`counter` is not entirely uninformative, but a better name would tell me *what* it counts. Similarly, it would be helpful to distinguish which variables relate to the search query and which to the items searched. The best convention I've seen there is PHP's `needle` and `haystack`, so I would suggest `needleLetters` and `haystackWords`.

---

#### foreach statement

Instead of `for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++) ... words[i]` you can use `for (String word : words) ... word`. This removes a variable and simplifies the naming, making it easier to see what the code does.

---

#### Decomposing strings

`String` has a method `toCharArray()`. I think it would make more sense to use that than `split("")`.

---

#### Don't put something in a loop which can go outside it

> ```
>             for(int j=0;j<words[i].length();j++)
>             {
>                 if(letters.length==ssplit.length)
>                 {
>                     ...
>                 }
>             }
> ```

could be rewritten

```
            if(letters.length==ssplit.length)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<ssplit.length;j++)
                {
                    ...
                }
            }
```

Executing the test once is more efficient, and it's also easier to understand because the maintainer doesn't have to reason about loop invariants to work out what might have changed the second time the test is executed.

Since there's nothing after this test in the loop body, an alternative would be

```
            if(letters.length!=ssplit.length)
            {
                continue;
            }

            for(int j=0;j<ssplit.length;j++)
            {
                ...
            }
```

---

#### Beware hard-coded constants

Why

```
                    if (counter == 4)
                    {
                        System.out.println(words[i]);
                    }
```

? That's a bug. The comparison should be with `letters.length`. Also, it would make more sense to move the test outside the loop over `j`.

---

#### Use advanced data structures

> ```
>             for(int j=0;j<words[i].length();j++)
>             {
>                 for(int k=0;k<letters.length;k++)
>                 {
>                     if(letters[j].equals(ssplit[k]))
>                     {
>                         counter++;
>                         ssplit[k]="*";
>                         break;
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
> ```

takes time proportional to `words[i].length() * letters.length`. If you use `java.util.HashMap<Character, Integer>` to store a per-character count, you can generate a representation for each word in time proportional to the length of the word, and you can compare the representations of two words in time proportional to the length of each word. In this toy example it doesn't matter, but for real applications the difference between \$O(n^2)\$ and \$O(n)\$ can be the difference between a project being feasible and not. The first place to look for optimisations is always the algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I had no clue that indentation could be so important. And I'll make sure I use better variable names. You mentioned a bug in the " if " statement. I understand that if the length of the search word and the words in the dictionary are greater than 4 than the results produced will not be accurate. But since I know the word-length and as long as it is not something the user will input, it is okay to use constants right?

Comment: One of the axes of code quality is brittleness. If changing the search word means that you have to make changes elsewhere, the code is brittle. The problem is that in six months you might have forgotten about the changes which you need to make elsewhere. Making the code less brittle now costs very little, and potentially saves a lot of debugging in the future.

Answer (score 0):

welcome on Codereview.

I am pretty sure that you will find many other ways to do it the comments from @NateGardner is already a good suggestion. But the goal is to review your code so I will just try to suggest some improvements to your code.

First of all I will just reformat the code, create a dedicated class for it and define the input and output.

```
class WordFinder {
  private final String[] words;
  WordFinder(String[] words) {
    this.words = new String[words.length];
    System.arraycopy(words, 0, this.words, 0, words.length);
  }
  String[] find(String word) {
    // Your code here
  }
}
```

Then you can start to split your nested logic in different methods and use exiting methods to simplify your code (like `String#toCharArray()` instead of `String#split("")`)

```
  String[] find(String word) {
    String[] result = new String[this.words.length];
    char[] letters = word.toCharArray();
    int counter = 0;
    for (String candidate : this.words) {
        if ( this.matches(letters, candidate.toCharArray()) ) {
            result[counter++] = candidate;
        }
    }
    return Arrays.copyOf(result, counter);
  }
```

As said in the beginning, there is a lot of way to test two words for matching and I am sure that you will find the best one. For this answer, I decided to compare the hash of each array of `char`.

---

Here is my code if you want. But if you can use other structure from the collections or the stream API, this one can be totally different.

```
public class WordFinder {

    private final String[] words;

    public WordFinder(String[] words) {
        this.words = new String[words.length];
        System.arraycopy(words, 0, this.words, 0, words.length);
    }

    public String[] find(String word) {
        String[] result = new String[this.words.length];
        char[] letters = word.toCharArray();
        int counter = 0;
        for (String candidate : this.words) {
            if ( matches(letters, candidate.toCharArray()) ) {
                result[counter++] = candidate;
            }
        }
        return Arrays.copyOf(result, counter);
    }

    private boolean matches(char[] requirement, char[] candidate) {
        /* Edited to replace Arrays.hashCode with Arrays.equals, see comments
        return candidate.length==requirement.length &&
           hash(candidate)==hash(requirement);*/

        if ( candidate.length!=requirement.length ) {
            return false;
        } 
        char left = Arrays.copyOf(requirement, requirement.length);
        Arrays.sort(left);
        char right = Arrays.copyOf(candidate, candidate.length);
        Arrays.sort(right );
        return Arrays.equals(left, right);
    }

    /*private int hash(char[] array) {
        char[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
        Arrays.sort(copy);
        return Arrays.hashCode(copy);
    }*/
}
```

Comment: The most significant suggestion of this answer introduces a bug. Comparing hashes is a valid way of showing that two objects are different, but it is not a valid way of showing that they're the same.

Comment: "For any two char arrays a and b such that `Arrays.equals(a, b)`, it is also the case that `Arrays.hashCode(a) == Arrays.hashCode(b)`."  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode(char[])

But if you prefer you can use `Arrays.equals` once they are sorted.

Comment: You are arguing my point. It doesn't say "*For any two char arrays a and b such that Arrays.hashCode(a) == Arrays.hashCode(b), it is also the case that Arrays.equals(a, b)*". And that can't be the case, if for no other reason then due to the pigeon-hole principle.

Comment: @PeterTaylor it may be due to the language that is not my native one. But I don't get the nuance. I will edit my code to replace the hash with `Arrays.equals`.

Comment: Perhaps mathematical notation translates better than natural language. \$A \implies B\$ is not the same as \$B \implies A\$. Knowing that \$A \implies B\$ and \$B\$ does not tell you anything about \$A\$. Here \$A\$ is `Arrays.equals(a, b)` and \$B\$ is `Arrays.hashCode(a) == Arrays.hashCode(b)`.